# Error reading html export from banking. R$0,64 is read as 64 type numpy.float64

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, locale

I am working on a program to read the HTML export from the bank to create a dataframe with expenses with Python.
When reading the HTML file with `df = pd.read_html(io='jan-2020.html')`, the column for credits reads the information as NumPy.float64 and misinterprets the locale so, 0,64 (64 cents with the **comma** as separator) is read to the dataframe as 64 (64 Brazilian reais) instead of 0.64 (64 cents). Another example, a credit of 2.650,73 is read as 2.65073 (the **comma** separating the centesimal part is simply disregarded).
I presume this has something to do with different locales of the system (macOS Catalina 10.15.7)  I am using and the banking system which exported the file (Brazilian bank).
If I run `locale.getlocale()` on my computer I get the following answer from the system: ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
How could this be corrected? I mean, how can I read the HTML exporte file and properly get the values correctly read (0,64 is read as 0.64) and so on?
Interestingly enough, the values in the next column in the HTML export are read as '**str**' but that I have already figured out.

Comment: Look the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html   you can set the thousand separator, the decimal separator, etc. Without messing with locales

Comment: Thank you Giacomo! That solves it.